# Google Drive - MultiSession Users

Tags: windows, hard-drive

I have one question based on one Use Case.

Recently, one department ask us to provide one VM in AWS, for Using that instance like a Big Processing Machine (c5 instance, etc).
The instance support multiple rdp-sessions at the same time.

NOW, we have aproblem, users needs to use Google Drive under each session, this app the Cloud Folders on one Logic Drive, assigning each user a different letter in each session.
As example:

User 1: D
User 2: E
User 3: F

etc.

Obviously this brokens the shortcuts.

There is a workaround for Fix All Sessions to Use the same G:\ Standard Letter?

Kind regards! =)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.